# Enable hyper-V on Windows 2012

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have a window7 (32 bit) machine. I installed Virtual Box and created a VM (Windows 2012 {64bit} with enabled VT-x/AMD-V,Nested Paging).

I want to enable Hyper-V on this VM any Idea?

I tried following links but not working for me:
  [Link1](http://www.rickygao.com/enable-hyper-v-under-vmware-workstation-for-your-lab/) 
  [Link2](http://www.mrxuri.com/2013/10/06/install-hyper-v-server-2012-in-vmware-workstation.html) 
but in my case I am using Virtual Box.

How can I enable Hyper-V feature?

Comment: Any other way to install or enable Hyper-V?

Comment: Probably a bios setting. I had the same problem last week: new computer, 32 bit VirtualBox VMs ran ok, 64 bit VMs said my processor was 32 bit only. Traced it to a Bios Setting "enable Virtualization", after turning that on, everything worked well.

Comment: @Guntram:  Visualization feature is enabled in my host machine and required setting for Visualization "VT-x/AMD-V" is also enable in Virtual box but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to expose VT-x/AMD-V to the guest system in the VM so it can run Hyper-V inside VM? As far as I know, VirtualBox does not support it, but VMWare does, even in their free VMWare Player.

I have been running Windows Phone 8 emulator in VMWare Player without problems. Yes, it required manual editing of .vmx file, but is works reliably and without any problems at all.

If you decide to give VMWare Player a try, make sure you have VT-x/AMD-V available and enabled on your physical host computer. Then add the following setting to your VMWare machine:

```
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
mce.enable = "TRUE"
```

and you should be able to start Hyper-V inside your VM.

For more information, see these links:

[Unable to use Hyper-V platform inside a Windows 8 virtual machine](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2044876)

[How to Enable Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V Role in VMware](http://jayrbarrios.com/2013/04/15/how-to-enable-windows-server-2012-hyper-v-role-in-vmware/)

and some useful topics on VirtualBox forums which explain why the feature is not available on VirtualBox:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=52625&p=304452

I really miss this feature on VirtualBox because I find VMWare Player to be bloated and it slows the host system down much more than VirtualBox does.